How can I record sound in python?
When recording sound in python with pyaudio and pyaudiowpatch, it sounds like a speaker put inside a tin can.
I have tried recording the desktop audio with stereo mix and loopback adapter but both of them are sounded like tin cans. When using voicemeter with both the loopback and stereo mix the audio was great. I am willing to learn a new library if it's necessary.(currently trying out sounddevice library). Also I won't like to save the audio to a file, I would like to send it with a socket to another PC but I have figured it out how to do that.
Edit 2:
This is how I record the sound:
import pyaudiowpatch as py

# Everything is correctly entered so it's not a config error

p = py.PyAudio()

for i in range(p.get_device_count()):
            device = p.get_device_info_by_index(i)
            if device['name'][:10].lower() == 'stereo mix' and device['hostApi'] == 2:
                input_device_index = device['index']

# input_device_index = p.get_default_wasapi_loopback()['index']

inp = p.open(format=py.paInt16, channels=2, rate=48000, input=True, frames_per_buffer=1024, input_device_index=input_device_index)

output_device_index = output_device_index = p.get_device_info_by_index(77)['index'] # My headphones 

out = p.open(format=py.paInt16, channels=2, rate=48000, output=True, frames_per_buffer=1024, output_device_index=output_device_index)

while True:
    data = inp.read(1024)

    out.write(data)

The code that finds the stereo mix is only finding one device, also I have tried with the stereo mixs index directly and still the same output.
Edit 3:
Changing smaplerate gives an error, and changing the paint16 to something else will still stay the same.
I have found a way to not use stereo mix, just installed jack audio connection kit.
But still tho, I really want to make it work without it or possibly create something similar to it in python if possible.

so what's your exact and specific question? You haven't posted the code you used to record sound for us to see why it sounds like this.

Now, code is there, and we can speculate a bit: Are you sure there is not more than one audio device which passes the guards in your if  testing name and hostAPI? If the OS exposes a simpler, downgraded internal device that could be the source of your problem.  Your coe as is will always pick the last listed device that passes the test - just adding a print along with the assignment of input_device_index would take that out of the way.

Have you tried changing the "open" function parameters ? sampling rate to 44100 or format py.paInt24 ?
